# XML column and row stores

Tags: sql, xml, database

I want to design a small clinic database with XML.
How can I use column stores with XML database.
Which queries should use column stores and row stores.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to create tables in that database. use `XML` data type for the columns.

For example:

Create table clinic
(
Name XML
)

I assume that you have already created a database, if not, then,

Create database [Name]

Next, try to create tables in that database. For db design, there are tons stuff need to be concerned, cannot be explained here.

Comment: I know how to create database. I want to learn the advantage of column stores against row stores. My simple database is              Doctor (doc_id, doc_name, specialty, salary, phone, address)
Patient (pat_id, pat_name, pat_gender, phone, address, birth_date, test_name,  test_result, payment)    Which fields should be stored as column store or row store?

Comment: you mean which should be treated as columns or rows? If so, all your mentioned should be taken as columns because they are the attributes. Rows are for records. And in SQL, any condition you specified in query is against column. For example, if you would like filter all Doctors whose doc_id are smaller than 10. You have to add `where doc_id<10`, which is utilizing the column attribute, otherwise, you cannot filter out such result.